# What happens after the Certificate in SQL Server gets expired?

Tags: sql-server, certificate, tde

I have a certificate with my SQL Server Database. What will happen after the certificate gets expired?

Will the record insertion, selection, deletion will work after certificate gets expired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your certificate gets expired there will be no effect. Certificate expiration is not enforced when the certificate is used for encryption.

Check [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d9a80843-51d9-469c-b14f-07f5e7827514/alter-the-expiration-date-of-my-certificate-tde-sql2008?forum=sqlsecurity) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Transparent Data Encryption. If the certificate that protects the database master key expires, I'm pretty sure that the database will fail to start.

Comment: yes i'm using the same, but I found nothing on the internet that what happens after it's get expired.

Comment: There will be no effect if certificate is expired according to this post. [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d9a80843-51d9-469c-b14f-07f5e7827514/alter-the-expiration-date-of-my-certificate-tde-sql2008?forum=sqlsecurity)